# why do i have the same applications in /bin and /usr/bin on linux mint

Tags: linux-mint

from what I understand, `/bin` contains binaries that are might be needed when the computer is first being booted, and `/usr/bin` contains general system wide binaries. however it seems that seems that the `/bin` directory contains exactly the same as the `/usr/bin` directory. why is this and isn't this just a waste of space?

I am using the latest version of linux mint.

Comment: history and symlink

Comment: `ls -l` will show you many are symlinks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do `$ ls -ld /bin`  and see:

`lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     7 mar 11  2021 /bin -> usr/bin`

i.e. /bin is a link to /usr/bin, in effect when you `ls ... /bin` you are actually looking in `/usr/bin/`
... so nothing strange here; you see the very same files.